# merge two linked sorted list but get unexpected answer

Tags: python

I wrote such a solution to `merge two sorted list`

> Merge two sorted linked lists and return it as a new list. The new list should be made by splicing together the nodes of the first two lists.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> Input: 1->2->4, 1->3->4
> Output: 1->1->2->3->4->4
> ```

My solution:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None
class Solution3:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        """
        Plan:
        Compare l1 and l2 and merge the remainders
        """
        head = ListNode(0) #create head to hold 
        l3 = ListNode(0)        
        head.next = l3 

        while l1 and l2: #assert both exist
            if l2.val < l1.val:
                l3 = l2 #build l3's node
                l2 = l2.next #this is i++ 
            else:
                l3 = l1
                l1 = l1.next     
            l3 = l3.next #find the next to build
        if l1:
            l3 = l1 
        if l2:
            l3 = l2

        return head.next
```

but get wrong answer

> Input
>
> [1,2,4]
>   [1,3,4]
>
> Output
>
> [0]
>
> Expected
>
> [1,1,2,3,4,4]

I checked but cannot find any problems with my logic.

Could you please help me out?

Comment: In your loop you never set the `.next` so what did you expect to obtain? You simply give different names to different objects without ever doing anything to them.

Comment: save the day, could you please transmit the comment to answer.@GiacomoAlzetta

Comment: @Alice  I think i have answered your problem

Comment: It may differ but if you still need changes i can comply. I hope you get the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `l3` is supposed to identify the place where a next node shall be appended, hence

```
   l3 = head
```

You need to append the head of one of lists given (`l1` or `l2`) to `l3`, but you don't.
And after you append the node you need to advance both the head pointer of the source list (`l1` or `l2`) and the tail pointer of the destination list (`l3`):

```
    while l1 and l2:     #assert both exist
        if l2.val < l1.val:
            l3.next = l2 #append new node to the resulting list
            l2 = l2.next #and skip it in the source list 
        else:
            l3.next = l1
            l1 = l1.next     
        l3 = l3.next     #find the next to build
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

    def insert(self,el):
        Node = self
        while Node:
            if Node.next==None:
                Node.next = ListNode(el)
                break
            else:
                Node =Node.next

    def prin(node):
        while node:
            if node.next:
                print(node.val,end='-> ')
            else:
                print(node.val)
            node = node.next



def mergeTwoLists(l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
    """
    Plan:
    Compare l1 and l2 and merge the remainders
    """
    _node = None
    if l1.val<l2.val:
        _node = ListNode(l1.val)
        l1 =l1.next
    else:
        _node = ListNode(l2.val)
        l2=l2.next

    l3 = _node        

    while l1 and l2: #assert both exist
        if l2.val < l1.val:
            l3.insert(l2.val)
            l2 = l2.next
        else:
            l3.insert(l1.val)
            l1 = l1.next     

    while l1:
        l3.insert(l1.val)
        l1 =l1.next

    while l2:
        l3.insert(l2.val)
        l2 = l2.next

    return l3


node1= ListNode(1)
node1.insert(2)
node1.insert(4)

node2 = ListNode(1)
node2.insert(3)
node2.insert(4)

solved_list = mergeTwoLists(node1,node2)
solved_list.prin()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns `head.next`, which is only modified in the following lines:

```
l3 = ListNode(0) # this is what's returned
head.next = l3
... # rest of the code changes l3, but never touches head.next
return head.next
```

You seem to assume that, with this setup, any assignments to `l3` will modify `head.next`, which is not correct. As it stands, the function will always return the newly created node with content 0.

A more correct approach would be:

```
# at the beginning
l3 = head # l3.next is now actually equivalent to head.next
...
# to add a node
l3.next = newnode
l3 = l3.next # moving the pointer to the newly added tail
```

Answer (score 0):

You're never changing the list structure (there are no assignments to any `next`s in the loop), you're just moving `l1`, `l2`, and `l3` along the input lists.
Then you return `head.next`, which is still the node you first assigned to it.

Since your approach with a sentinel node makes the code much simpler than without, I've kept it here:

```
def merge(l1, l2):
    first = ListNode(0)
    # 'here' is where we link in the nodes.
    here = first
    while l1 and l2:
        # Pick the next node from the inputs.
        # Note that this has the same effect as assigning
        # to 'first.next' on the first iteration, when 'first' and 'here'
        # refer to the same object.
        if l1.val < l2.val:
            here.next = l1
        else:
            here.next = l2
        # Move along to the last node we picked.
        here = here.next
    # Grab the rest.
    if l1:
        here.next = l1
    else:
        here.next = l2
    return first.next
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None


class Solution3:
    def merge_two_lists(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode):

        head = ListNode(None)
        l3 = ListNode(None)
        head.next = l3

        while l1 and l2:
            if l2.val < l1.val:
                l3.next = l2
                l2 = l2.next
            else:
                l3.next = l1
                l1 = l1.next
            l3 = l3.next
        if l1:
            l3.next = l1
        if l2:
            l3.next = l2

        head = head.next
        return head.next


head_0, head_0.next, head_0.next.next = ListNode(1), ListNode(2), ListNode(4)
head_1, head_1.next, head_1.next.next = ListNode(1), ListNode(3), ListNode(4)


no = Solution3().merge_two_lists(head_0, head_1)
while no:
    print("Singly-linked list: {}".format(no.val))
    no = no.next
```

Output:

```
Singly-linked list: 1
Singly-linked list: 1
Singly-linked list: 2
Singly-linked list: 3
Singly-linked list: 4
Singly-linked list: 4
```